# Редактирование iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! У меня есть такой iframe:

```
<iframe src="file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/" id="body"></iframe>
```

Файл с кодом на локалке. Так вот, как можно редактировать содержимое такого iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> file:///

По идее браузер сюда не должен доступ давать.

Если нужно для тестов и внешний файл тоже локальный, попробуй запустить Хром так

```
chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```